# What are the major difference between ElasticSearch and OpenSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

We are planning to leverage OpenSearch for the XDR kind of project. We want to leverage most of the major features like Alerting, Detection, Machine Learning for Anomaly Detection, etc. So, I want to know that, are there any downsides of using OpenSearch instead of Elasticsearch for this particular use case.

I also didn’t find any proper comparison between Elasticsearch vs OpenSearch over the internet. So, can someone please provide the link or resource where I can have a detailed comparison?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenSearch is provided by AWS is it a kind of forked of ElasticSearch solution.
[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/aws/amazon-elasticsearch-service-is-now-amazon-opensearch-service-and-supports-opensearch-10/) you have the feature provided by OpenSearch.
Your feature requests are present on this list.

To have more details and a nuanced point of view, you have to read [this post](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/opensearch) provided by ElasticSearch.

And a [paper](https://pureinsights.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Elasticsearch-vs-OpenSearch-Business-Decision-Tree-1.pdf) that make a part of comparaison.

Comment: it's not "kind of forked", it is a definitive fork. as such it's no longer Elasticsearch or Kibana :)

Comment: I find it hard to believe that a post from elastic search themselves will provide the complete picture. They are incentivized to portray their own product as superior.

Comment: From [the post by ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/elasticsearch/opensearch): "Elasticsearch emerges as the clear choice", "Elasticsearch and Kibana offer superior product capabilities and maturity". This does not read like an objective comparison to me. @EmptySpace is right.